# Adjust paper size on crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I am using crystal report 2008. I have set the paper size on printer setup that didn't work.How to adjust the paper size in crystal report 2008?

Answer (score 0):

Click On Crystal Report -> Design -> printer setup -> change page layout (as per your requirement)